# Css hover isn't working

Tags: html, css, html-table, hover

Here is my code. I made this - when I hover table cell then its background image changes, that was easy.
But I would like to make that when I hover cell 5 with class="down" in first table then second table display attribute changes from none to block
I searched for this and I ended up with all this code, and it isn't working.
I need to use pure CSS without JavaScript.
Where is the problem and what did I do wrong?

HTML

```html
  <table border="0" class="table">
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>

      <td>2</td>

      <td>3</td>

      <td>4</td>

      <td class="down">5</td>
    </tr>
  </table>

  <table border="0" class="table2">
    <tr>
      <td>row2</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>row3</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
```

CSS

```css
.table
{
    left:200px;
    position:absolute;
}

td
{
    background-image:url(poga1.png);
    height:70px;
    width:100px;
}

td:hover
{
    -webkit-transition:1s;
    background-image:url(poga2.png);
}

.table2
{
    display:none;
    left:616px;
    position:absolute;
    top:77px;
}

.down:hover .table2
{
    display:block;
}
```

Comment: You cannot do that with css.

Comment: well it is possible with css if you have your table 2 inside of cell 5

Comment: That's bad, is there any way to make something similar?

Comment: @Huangism Could you please tell me how?

Comment: your css looks like it is targeting table2 which is inside of .down

Comment: if your table2 needs to be outside of cell 5 then you cannot do it with css

Comment: Maby I can make 5 different tables with 1 row and 1 column but 5th with 3 rows and when I hover 5th table 1 row its show those two others?

Comment: @Marc: I'm pretty certain it *can't*, because CSS has no way of targeting the second `table` based on hovering the `.down` element that's within the first `table` element; this would require CSS 4's ability to select an ancestor based on its child.

Comment: I agree with @DavidThomas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't really do this with CSS unless Table2 is a child of Table1.  It can be done very easily with JavaScript though (w/ jQuery in this instance).  Check out my example here:

http://jsfiddle.net/Pb8dw/1/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".down").mouseover(function(){
        $(".table2").show();
    });

    $(".down").mouseout(function(){
        $(".table2").hide();
    });
});
```

This is the block of code that does the hide/show on hover.  I took the liberty of updating your source code so it's easier to see.

Update: If you absolutely, positively, had to do it without JavaScript, here's how it would be down with just CSS and HTML:

http://jsfiddle.net/Pb8dw/2/

Comment: We haven't learned about that in school yet, so I cant use what I haven't learnt about.

Comment: And comment deleted (also: I wouldn't say it was *egregious*, just needed to be clarified was all). @jjanko3: there's no way to do this, using CSS (except in very particular situations).

Comment: Sorry David, didn't mean to come off as snarky.  I like it when people call out my mistakes, I just tend to use flowery language and forgot I'm on the internet, where any use of it can come off as sarcastic.

Comment: @jjanko3 I updated my comment with a second link.  That's how it could be down with just CSS and HTML.  You'll notice that Table2 is now a child of .down.  In this case, CSS is really only affective at manipulating a DOM Object and it's descendants (and not it's parent's siblings like you were trying to).

Comment: @LNendza Maby I can make 5 different tables with 1 row and 1 column but 5th with 3 rows and when I hover 5th table 1 row its show those two others?  Then I would get that other table cells doesn't change their size. right?

Comment: Yes, you could do exactly that.

Comment: Check out my link again - http://jsfiddle.net/Pb8dw/2/ - I believe this is what you are looking for

Answer (score 0):

The line `.down:hover .table2` is looking for an element with class `table2` *inside* an element with class `down`. You can only do what you want in pure CSS if your tables are nested. Here's how you might do what you want using jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.down').hover(function() {
        $('.table2').show();
    }, function() {
        $('.table2').hide();
    });
});
```

Here's a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/mchail/b6PKT/

I added a border on the `td` elements so it's easier to see when your hover event should trigger.

Comment: Maby I can make 5 different tables with 1 row and 1 column but 5th with 3 rows and when I hover 5th table 1 row its show those two others?

Comment: It sounds like you would try to show additional `td` elements when you hover over the root `table` element. That would probably work. It looks like you're trying to make a nested dropdown, which is more often done using `ul`s and `li`s. If you want to do this in pure CSS, you should look at the example here: (http://csswizardry.com/2011/02/creating-a-pure-css-dropdown-menu/), with a demo: (http://csswizardry.com/demos/css-dropdown/). There's no shame in using jQuery (or another javascript library) to accomplish this either.

Comment: Thanks, I will use then those ul and li, at least try to use them. Thanks.